# Manipulate two arrays, so all indices should have the same value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have to arrays, `$array1` and `$array2` as follow:

```
$bool = true;
$array2 = array('p1' => false, 'p2' => false);
$array1 = array('p3', 'p4', 'p5');
```

Now I want to merge these arrays and the result array should be as follow:

```
// All equal to $bool
$array3 = array('p1' => true, 'p2' => true, 'p3' => true, 'p4' => true, 'p5' => true);
```

How to do that like a geek?

**Note** I can do it in some loops, but I'm looking for a better solution with lesser loops or maybe a trick which could perform better. for e.g. using `array_merge` or `array_fill` or etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_fill_keys(
    array_merge(
        array_keys($array2), 
        $array1
    ),
    $bool
);
```